# How do I accurately align the spikes of my star to the faces that they protrude from?

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make a simple spiked star shape. I want to move the vertices in the same direction that the faces are facing, which gets complicated when I have to move across all three axes. I doubt that I can do this without using some sort of specific orientation, and I don't know much about Blender.

In short, my problem is that I have no idea what I'm doing.

I've messed around with it for at least 6 hours and the closest that I've gotten to accuracy was being able to line up the direction of the protruding lines with the tip of the pentagon in a top-down, orthographic view.

[image: example]

[image: my model]

*The dodecahedron was made by chandlerklebs on sketchfab*

Comment: There is an included add on in blender called Extra Objects, this has a Simple Star shape ready to be use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to do it "manually":

1. enable

[image]

2. Shift-A -> mesh -> math function

[image]

3. change to dodecahedron

[image]

4. TAB -> edit mode -> select edge

[image]

5. select -> similar -> length

[image]

6. x -> dissolve edges

[image]

7. face select mode -> select all (A) -> mesh -> split -> faces by edges

[image]

8. CTRL -E > extrude faces along normals

[image]

9. [image]

choose individual origins

[image]

10. S 0

[image]

Comment: Oh!!! I was told normals were a lighting trick. That's why I didn't mess with that option. They're much more simple than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't as useful as [Chris's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270798/35559), it's too tricksy. But the star can be made in 2 moves, from a *Mesh > Math Function > Regular Solid > Dodecahedron*:

1. <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* on edges..
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (Face Menu) > *Poke Faces*, and adjust offset.

[image]

Offset values greater than 1 can be typed in.